# Linux Firefox 8 Flash plugin doesn't play any sound?

Tags: firefox, flash, opensuse

On my Linux box my flash plugin doesn't play any sound? I've updated firefox with zypper up and I have the newest OpenSuse 11.4 but I'm using a custom and updated kernel from zen-kernel.org and usually I compile my kernel myself with a custom config file. How can I get flash to play any sound?

Comment: Which version of Adobe Flash Player did you install?

Comment: Maybe that's the problem. Isn't the plugin get's updated with the repos or with firefox? I will check with Chrome, too?

Comment: When did you start having problems with Flash? Or has this always happened for your set up?

Comment: No, not always I think it comes with a kernel update or even with an OS upgrade. It doesn't play any sound but I'm not sure if my sound driver works at all. I will check with a sound first.